# @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) not working properly?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a simple moderator bot.
the code looks something like this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice
import os


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("%"), description='A simple Moderator bot')

def colour():
  l = [ 1752220, 3066993, 3447003, 10181046, 15844367, 15105570, 15158332, 3426654, 16580705 ]
  return choice(l)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  change_status.start()
  print("The Bot is online!")


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, user : discord.Member = None, *,reason = "No reason provided"):
  await user.kick(reason = reason)
  await ctx.send("Kicked the user.")
 

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, user : discord.Member = None, *,reason = "No reason provided"):
      await user.ban(reason = reason)
      await ctx.send("Banned the user")
    

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warn(ctx, user : discord.Member = None, *,reason = "No reason provided"):
      await user.send(f"You have been **Warned** by **{ctx.author.name}** in the **{ctx.guild.name}** for the reason: **{reason}** ")
      await ctx.send("Warned the user")
    

client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

In this only warn command is working successfully rest all the commands throws an error which looks like this.

```
Ignoring exception in command kick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 140, in kick
await user.kick(reason = reason)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 524, in kick
await self.guild.kick(self, reason=reason)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1886, in kick
await self._state.http.kick(user.id, self.id, reason=reason)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

It is throwing a missing permission but I am the owner of the server and even added the bot as an admistrator.
Even tried by making an administrator role and giving all the permissions to it but still no luck.
This error is coming again and again.

Even if anyone know how to check between multiple roles like if anyone has administrator **or** kick member permission then do this, please let me know how to do that.
Thanks in advance for the help.
If any more information needed, do let me know.

Comment: Does the user that you are trying to kick have Administrator role as well? The bot cannot kick someone with a role with higher hierarchy than him.

Comment: ohhhh yes. I tried to kick the bot and the bot was having administrator permission.

Can you tell how to resolve this issue. Like there should be a way to kick the bots with administrator role too.

Comment: Your bot should not have administrator role, and a bot will never be able to kick somebody with higher role hierarchy than himself.

Comment: so is there a way to make the highest role which can kick everyone except the owner

Comment: Just create a role for the bot and in the role hierarchy place it just below the admin/owner role. It will be able to kick everyone except the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting on the last line from your console; `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` Is because the bot is missing permissions to perform these actions against the given permissions the bot currently has.

This could occur from the following;

- Sufficient Bot permissions haven't been enabled from the invite link
- The member has a higher or equal role than the bot
- The @everyone role has no permissions

Moreover, these issues aren't at fault with the code you have written and is something that can be fixed in your server with the role hierarchy or bot invite link permissions.

I would also recommend comparing roles to make sure users can't attempt moderation on a higher level member in the first place, this could also help to mitigate the problem

With this, you can use `>=` and the `top_role` attribute which would compare the roles that the user compared to the member you are attempting to take moderation on, if your permissions are lower than the member you are attempting to moderate, it will prevent the rest of the code running. Here is a simple way of doing this,

```
if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
    await ctx.send(f"You can only moderate members below your role")         
    return
```